# Updates multiple tables in hibernate and ensure data consistency

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am new to hibernate.Started exploring yesterday itself. I am stuck and wondering whether this could be done with Hibernate or not.

Lets say I have three tables Table A ( which has columns **name, budget, bid, status , date**), Table B ( **id, budget, bid**) and table C ( **id, status**). I want all data to be consistent i.e whenever the update happen in Table B (lets say for budget the new value should get reflected in Table A). Same applies whenever update happen in Table C also. What is the best way to achieve this in hibernate?

Comment: Why your tables are not normalized ? Why do you have the same data in multiple tables ?

Comment: Try normalizing the tables and it'll take care of it. Duplication of data could be a major pain.

Comment: That is the requirement. We want to track the change of status,budget,bid in separate table

Comment: So, the tables are independent, is it ? They do not have any relationship primary key forighkey ?

Comment: The tables are independent with no foreign key constraints

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't recommend data duplication across multiple tables, which is very hard to support and maintain.

But as you are stating that it is your main requirement, you need to use **JPA Entity Listeners (works with Hibernate plus across all ORM frameworks)** `postUpdate()` and `postInsert()` so that whenever there is an update/insert to the Table B, then create & persist one more object (row in database) into Table A.

Below is the point taken from JPA spec. for your reference.

> PostUpdate callback occur after the database update operations to
>   entity data respectively.

You can find a simple example [here](http://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove)

Answer (score -1):

you should use trigger by firing event on insertion of data in table B which will reflect data in table table A

Comment: User asked how to do it using hibernate, further a bad DB design should not be encouraged by providing patches like solutions.